# I am seeing error "Call to undefined function pods()" even though pods() is defined

Tags: php, wordpress, undefined

Inside WordPress I have two plugins.

The first plugin is named Pods, and it has a `pods()` function.

The second plugin (which I created) is a simple addon to Pods, and it makes use of the `Pods()` function, like so:

```
<?php

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) or die( 'No script kiddies please!' );

//Get the pod for the current post where this shortcode will be appearing
$pod = pods( get_post_type(), get_the_ID() );

//Build the name shortcode
add_shortcode( 'my_name', 'bg_my_name_shortcode' );
function bg_my_name_shortcode($pod) {
    $my_name = $pod->display('my_name');
    return $my_name;
}
```

But this is causing an error `Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function pods()` for some reason, even though `pods()` was defined in the other Pods plugin and it was designed to extended like this: https://pods.io/docs/code/pods/

If I move `$pod = pods( get_post_type(), get_the_ID() );` inside the `bg_my_name_shortcode` function it works fine, but I have many of these shortcodes to make so I don't want to call those three functions (`pods()`, `get_post_type()`, `get_the_ID()`) over and over again instead of calling it once and storing it as a variable.

I'm also confused at why this would happen, since `pods()` is definitely a defined function in the Pods plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you get that error is because the plugin that defines that function is not loaded yet.

You need to declare the short-code after WordPress is initialized, and all plugins are loaded.
Try this code:

```
<?php

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) or die( 'No script kiddies please!' );

function bg_my_name_shortcode_init(){
    //Get the pod for the current post where this shortcode will be appearing
    $pod = pods( get_post_type(), get_the_ID() );

    //Build the name shortcode
    add_shortcode( 'my_name', 'bg_my_name_shortcode' );
    function bg_my_name_shortcode($pod) {
        $my_name = $pod->display('my_name');
        return $my_name;
    }
}
add_action('init', 'bg_my_name_shortcode_init');
```

More details can be found [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/shortcodes/basic-shortcodes/#in-a-plugin)

#### Edit

Fixing the `Uncaught Error: Call to a member function display() on string` error:

```
<?php

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) or die( 'No script kiddies please!' );

function bg_my_name_shortcode_init(){

    function bg_my_name_shortcode() {
        //Get the pod for the current post where this shortcode will be appearing
        $pod = pods( get_post_type(), get_the_ID() );
        $my_name = $pod->display('my_name');
        return $my_name;
    }
    //Build the name shortcode
    add_shortcode( 'my_name', 'bg_my_name_shortcode' );

}
add_action('init', 'bg_my_name_shortcode_init');
```

Comment: Thanks, that has removed the original error, but now I am seeing `Uncaught Error: Call to a member function display()` on the front end where the shortcode should appear.

Comment: Sorry the full error is `Uncaught Error: Call to a member function display() on string`.

Comment: Going to re-post as it's own question because I think it's unreleated.